# How to ignore my inventory option in .ansible.cfg?

Tags: ansible

I've double-checked that Ansible is reading my `.ansible.cfg` file (it is).

However, if I use the setting:

```
inventory      = /my/local/inventory
```

I keep getting the error message `No hosts matched` if I ignore the `-i` option when running `ansible`.

I've tried `ansible -vvv` but that hasn't shed any light.

I've also looked at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11907 and checked there aren't any `ENV` variables set.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is `inventory` under the `[defaults]` section header in .ansible.cfg?  Can your post your full .ansible.cfg?

Comment: The question can be shortened to: "I'm doing everything properly, but it's not working, any other suggestions?" without any loss of information. Do you really think it's answerable?

Comment: maybe the current folder have it's own `ansible.cfg` file ?

Comment: `ansible --version` shows what config file is being used.

Comment: `ansible --version` gives me just `ansible 1.5.4`

Comment: @Snowcrash time for an upgrade, then you will see a decent version not full of bugs and security holes (current version is 2.9.x, [yours was released in 2014](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases/tag/v1.5.4)) + a list of helpful info including which config file is currently being used from your current location.

Answer (score 1):

You said `.ansible.cfg` which is the file it will search for in your home directory. If you are expecting an Ansible configuration for the current directory, make sure it is called `ansible.cfg`. See the [docs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg#L4-L8) for more information on search order for Ansible config.